# Get Current Controller name from outside a view and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controllercontext

I have tried using the ControllerContext object, but I don't know how to instantiate it.
I'd like to remind you that I'm trying to get the controller name in a custom class outside a view or a controller.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. Simply pass the controller name as parameter from within the controller to whatever class needs it. *Current controller* is a notion that doesn't make sense from outside of a controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to clarify, I have a followup question -- I'm actually using MvcSiteMapProvider and have a GetDynamicNodeCollection class which handles dynamic nodes. In that class I have a method which requires the controller name in order to make it more generic. I cannot call that method from the controller... what can I do in this scenario ? -- I'm sorry again if this seems out of context. if it is I'll post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @user560498, you should post a different question explaining your scenario and provide sample code.